# URL that causes redirect is loaded twice by Safari

Tags: redirect, safari, http-headers

A given URL

`www.example.com/a`

redirects the client to a different location:

`www.somesite.com/b`

---

If I access the (first) URL using **Safari** (9.1.3) I am correctly redirected to the new location, however the original URL `www.example.com/a` **is loaded twice**

This does not happen with **Firefox** or **Chrome** browsers, the only other user agents I tested so far for this issue.

---

I have proof of this behaviour from the **web server access log** (nginx).

Furthermore when `www.example.com/a` is accessed a record is added into a log table in the `example.com` server's database. Accessing the URL with Safari causes two record being created.

---

I have recorded that the first URL is hit the second time (approximately) 0 to 3 seconds later.

I tried different redirect *flavours*, with both status `302 Found` and `303 Other`.

I tried too to specify (in the HTTP header) a expire time in the past and to set it in the future (5 - 15 - 3700 seconds ahead).

None of these changes have caused any difference.

---

**The question is:** is there something wrong in the reroute response header causing this or I just stumbled upon some Safari weird *feature* ?

My redirect response header looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 25 Feb 2017 23:24:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Fat-Free Framework
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: max-age=15
Expires: Sat, 25 Feb 2017 23:24:34 +0000
Last-Modified: Sat, 25 Feb 2017 23:24:19 +0000
Location: http://www.somesite.com/b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found this is a harmless bug in Safari 9 that occurrs only when the URL (that will cause the redirect) is typed (or pasted) into the address bar.

Accessing the URL via a html link on a webpage (or a link in an application like Mail for example) doesn't cause the double hit on the URL.

Also **the issue disappeared in Safari 10**.